# Will a Muslim be held accountable for being a witness to lies?

Tags: sharia

It is reported that:

> حَدَّثَنَا يَحْيَى بْنُ مُوسَى، حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الرَّزَّاقِ، عَنْ
> مَعْمَرٍ، عَنْ أَيُّوبَ، عَنِ ابْنِ أَبِي مُلَيْكَةَ، عَنْ عَائِشَةَ،
> قَالَتْ مَا كَانَ خُلُقٌ أَبْغَضَ إِلَى رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه
> وسلم مِنَ الْكَذِبِ...
>
> "Aishah narrated: *[**"There was no behavior more hated to the Messenger
> of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) than lying ...."**](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:1973)*

A lot of Muslim-Majority country have in their constitutions that;

الإسلام دين الدولة، واللغة العربية لغتها الرسمية، ومبادئ الشريعة الإسلامية المصدر الرئيسي للتشريع.

> "Islam is the religion of the state and Arabic is its official
> language. The principles of Islamic Sharia are the principle source of
> legislation."*

But are they "**lying**" when they fail to live up to the claim that, "***Islam is the religion of the state***" and that, "**The principles of Islamic Sharia are the principle source of legislation.**"?

For example, almost all permit riba, some alcohol, etc.